# How to run a Docker image in Open server without using the docker container

Tags: docker, jenkins, cluster-computing, hierarchical-clustering, docker-image

I'm setting up a cluster environment with 7 servers and I have a already created docker image which I have configured our application. I need to use that docker image inside my open server but not Inside the docker as it affects the performance when we are doing load tests.

I'm using Ubuntu servers and all configurations are done by Jenkins jobs using ssh.

My ultimate outcome is to reset the cluster environment each time when I executing the Jenkins jobs for each new release of our application. Is there a way to do that??

Comment: I am not sure that I get your problem. Do you want to just clean the docker in your servers? "docker system prune -a" may be the solution.

Comment: No, I want to execute docker image directly on my server without the docker container.so that I can use the server space  and it's not affecting the performance when running load tests

Comment: as far as I know, no way to do this. You may use vm snapshot rather than container.

Comment: as far as I know, no way to do this. You may use vm snapshot rather than container.

Comment: can you please send me if there are any documents or links related to vm snapshot

Comment: https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-9/topic/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-85B0A264-58DB-49B3-9C6C-4E84068D8D17.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to deploy docker image as vm or physical server. 
Docker image can be used only on docker server as far as I know.

As @paco alcacer told in comments, best solution to you if you are using virtual environment for example (vsphere/esxi), is to create one virtual machine that will contain all necessary applications for cluster, then simply clone this virtual machine across other servers in cluster.
There are several tools for this depending on what environment you are using